# Ccan't create a list in R of size more than 79

Tags: r

I have around 85 lists of different sizes, L1 - L85
I'm trying to create a new list in the following way:

```
allLists <- list(a = L1, b = L2, c = L3,....nn = L85)
```

This code is dynamically generated by Java which creates the lists for later statistical calculations.
When I run the code all I get is a + after the end of the command.
If I remove some of the lists and reduce the size if the allLists list to 79 or less
the code runs without a problem, otherwise there's just + .
Any Idea will be appreciated.

So I'm using RCaller library in Java. 
The target is to perform statistical analysis on Experiments with x traits and n repetitions.
First of all I'm building lists which contain all the calculations for each event for example AVG, MED etc., Later I need to build the "Master List" which contains all the events lists with all their calculations to run some statistical models on them.
Basically the `allLists` looks as follows:

```
allLists <- list(trait1STDEV = res.trait1STDEV, trait1MeasureN = res.trait1MeasureN, trait1MeasureIMP = res.trait1MeasureIMP, trait1MeasureSIG = res.trait1MeasureSIG, trait2AVG = res.trait2AVG, trait2STDEV = res.trait2STDEV...........traitNSIG = res.traitNSIG)
```

Comment: I suspect its a parser line length problem. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: If I do `l=list(a1=1, a2=2, a3=3, a4=4, a5=5 ....` etc up to 100 it works for me, whether its on the command line or source'd in from a file. How exactly are you running this? Maybe its Windows' fault.

Comment: So now write a teeny tiny Java example that builds a big list (like I did in my test) and shows it failing. Make it some Java we can all run without needing all your code. Otherwise we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the problem. Apparently there's a limit on the maximum command length in R,
this problem can be solved by feeding a new line when working in console.
However when using the `RUtils` in Java this solution is not applicable.
In the case when generation R code with Java by using `RUtils` there's a need to install a package called `Runiversal` after doing that there's no problem with maximum command length.